# How can I hide the quote marks?

Tags: python

I have to make a maths test in Python for school but instead of a question like `6 + 8?`, it comes out like this `(6, '+', 8)`.

Here is my code:

```
print ('What is your name?')
name = input()
print (' Hello ' + name +', Welcome to the python maths quiz by Tom Luxton, you will be asked 10 maths questions and marked out of 10 at the end, good luck! ')

import random

ops = ['+', '-', '*']
num1 = random.randint(1,12)
num2 = random.randint(1,10)
op = random.choice(ops)
answer = num1, op, num2
print(answer)
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun: nope, not the right answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: because the OP doesn't have a string. They are printing a **tuple**.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: which goes to show that you shouldn't jump to conclusions without seeing code! :-P

Answer (score 5):

You are printing a *tuple*, `answer`. Either print the individual elements or turn that tuple into a string first.

Printing the elements of the tuple can be done by passing them to `print()` using the `*args` syntax:

```
print(*answer)
```

or by not creating a tuple in the first place but by instead passing the arguments to `print()` separately:

```
print(num1, op, num2)
```

You could turn the tuple into a string first by mapping all values to strings and joining them manually with a space:

```
answer = ' '.join(map(str, answer))
```

or you could use string formatting with `str.format()`:

```
answer = '{} {} {}?'.format(num1, op, num2)
```

which has the added advantage that it is now easy to add that `?` question mark you wanted.